# How to make selected link in Navigation highlighted without redirecting page in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list of links. I want to make selected link as highlighted when clicked on that but without redirecting to the page. Following is the code for that.

HTML

```
  <ul class="nav nav-list"> 
    <li ng-repeat="navLink in navLinks" ng-class="navClass('{{navLink.Title}}')">
       <a href='#/{{navLink.Title}}'>{{navLink.LinkText}}</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
 app.controller('CreatorController', function($scope,$rootScope,$location,$http,CreatorService,FlashService) {
$scope.navLinks = [{
        Title: 'home',
        LinkText: 'Home',
    }, {
        Title: 'about',
        LinkText: 'About Us'
    }, {
        Title: 'contact',
        LinkText: 'Contact Us'
    }];

    $scope.navClass = function (page) {
        var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'home';
        return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
    };
});
```

Above code runs well, whenever I click on one of those links it highlights that link but it redirecting to that particular page. 
I want to show it as selected but don't want to redirect to page when I click on link. What will be the changes in my code?

Comment: so, if you click the link, you should not redirect to that page, but you should stay in your current page itself, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you requirement, you can use `ng-dblclick` which will execute only on double click. So, when the user clicks your link, it will be highlighted but will not redirect to that page.

You can write a function in controller for redirecting the page. Lets say you created "redirectPage" function in controller, then your link will be like:

```
<a ng-dblclick="redirectPage()">link</a>
```

Here is the functionality of ng-dblclick. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9agt8g6/1/)

Hope it works :)

Comment: no problem man :) . If it works, make it as correct answer. Thanks